# V-validate on dynamic custom component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I am using Vee-validate (https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/) to validate all my forms. Now I would like to do the following:

In my form the "value" field is a dynamic component, depending on the `type` of the current object. Type can be `integer`, `string`, `decimal` etc.

So if the type changes,  the input changes, too.

This is how I did  this:

```
   <component
     :name="'attribute-value'"
     v-model="attribute.value"
     :is="attribute.type">
   </component>
```

And

```
import string from '@/components/fields/String'
import integer from '@/components/fields/Integer'
import decimal from '@/components/fields/Decimal'

export default {
  name: 'edit',
  metaInfo: {
    title: 'Edit'
  },
  components: {
    string, integer, decimal
  },
}
```

Alright - each field should have it's own validation. The `integer`-field should only allow numbers. So I would like to do this:

```
<template>
    <b-input
      :id="name"
      :name="name"
      type="number"
      v-validate="{ required: true, numeric: true }"
      :state="errors.has(name) ? 'invalid' : ''"
      :value="value"
      v-on:input="$emit('input',$event)"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Integer',
    inject: {
        $validator: '$validator'
    },
    props: ['name', 'value'],

    $_veeValidate: {
        name() {
            return this.name;
        },
        value() {
            return this.value;
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately, there are no errors shown, if I enter something else than a number. And: The submit-method on the parent component does not prevent the submission.

I am thankful for all of your comments :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use v-bind to pass any data to the component instead of v-model. Another way to do is, you can create one generic component, say **BaseInput** which takes yours input current object as props. Inside your **BaseInput** component you can select your Integer or String component using v-if, like this.

```
<template v-if="inputCurrentObject.type === 'string' ">
  <Integer :input="inputCurrentObject.value" />
</template>
```

Inside your **BaseInput** you can render the components based on the input type.